Getting deflate.dll not found error when running code
I'm new to GDAL but I managed to get it to build in Visual Studio 2022 with the help of this forum. I was also able to get my own project that uses GDAL to build in Visual Studio C++. But when I run it, I get a message that:

The code execution cannot proceed because deflate.dll was not found.

The problem seems to originate in the GDAL. Just calling GDALAllRegister() causes it. I looked through the GDAL build for any reference to "deflate.dll", but I only find deflate.c and deflate.h. There doesn't seem to be a subproject that builds a "deflate.dll".
Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

Maybe you could try first if GDAL_USE_DEFLATE=OFF makes the error to disappear https://gdal.org/en/latest/development/building_from_source.html#deflate

You need to install or build libdeflate first.

Thanks. That helps. It seems I also need to do the same for (at minimum) blosc.dll, xerces-c_3_2.dll, tiff.dll, geotiff.dll and libpng16.dll. I'll pick through them one by one. Hopefully that'll be everything.

Actually, never mind... I found all the DLLs that GDAL needs in my \miniconda3\envs\gdal\Library\bin\ folder. It works now.
